# Restriction on Code inside Catch Block

Tags: c#

Can we write any code statement inside a Catch block of try catch in c#,
Or is there any restriction on what we cannot or should not write inside Catch block of C#?

Comment: Sure you can. Can you show an example for that?

Comment: What's your mean clearly? catch block is a block like if, for and ... block and hasn't any restrict to writing any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `yield` or `await` inside a catch block. So the following two won't compile:

```
public IEnumerable<int> SomeSequence()
{
    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch
    {
        yield 1; //error
    }
}
```

or

```
public async int SomeFuncAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //error
    }
}
```

You can easily work around this though:

```
public async int SomeFuncAsync()
{
    Exception ex = null;
    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        ex = exc;
    }
    if(ex != null) await Task.Delay(1000); // no error
}
```

Comment: `await` in catch will be possible in vnext. The limitation for `yield` will still hold I believe

Comment: thanks for answer. I would wait for some more answer.